# Confusing multivariable chain rule question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I am currently doing chain rule exercises and I encountered this one:

Calculate the derivative of $g(f(x,y))$ at $(1,0)$:

\begin{align*}
f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3, f(x,y) &= (x^2 +\sin (y), xy, \sin(xy))\\
g: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2, g(x,y,z) &= (xy^2+z, \frac{1}{x^2 + z^2})
\end{align*}

By 'the derivative' I imagine they mean the directional derivative at $(0,1)$ given by a general $(x,y)$ vector. My question lies with how do we process this derivative? I've done other examples but none as confusing as this one.

Comment: there seems to be a mistake. $g\circ f:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^2$, so the derivative would need to be evaluated at a point in $3$ space. Unless they wish you to solve $xy^2+z=1$ and $\frac{1}{x^2+z^2}=0$ which seems unlikely, as this has no solutions.

Comment: Have you learned about the derivative as a matrix, or as a linear map?  This question makes sense:  the answer is a certain $2 \times 3$ matrix.  It can be computed directly (by composing the functions and differentiating) or by using the chain rule (which involves multiplying a $2 \times 3$ and a $3 \times 3$ matrix together).

Depending on if any of this sounds familiar, maybe your instructor just made a mistake by including this question.  It would be fair game in my calc 3 courses, but maybe not in your instructors.

Comment: I've studied the derivative more as a linear map, but my teacher taught it also as a matrix, although I haven't studied that part yet.

Comment: Matrices are (among other things) representations of linear maps.